# ExoPlayer how to save cache?

Tags: android, video, exoplayer

How to save cache on sdcard in Android ExoPlayer?

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer.html

Is it real?

Comment: why this is unclear? that's good question and answer :|

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a relatively simple approach (however a bit naive) that works for most simple test cases, you can then proceed to extend it to suit your needs and maybe even improve and contribute to the official ExoPlayer project.

I've implemented it like this in the renderer builder

```
Cache cache = new SimpleCache(context.getCacheDir(), new LeastRecentlyUsedCacheEvictor(1024 * 1024 * 10));

DataSource dataSource = new DefaultUriDataSource(context, bandwidthMeter, userAgent);
CacheDataSource cacheDataSource = new CacheDataSource(cache, dataSource, false, false);
HlsChunkSource chunkSource = new HlsChunkSource(cacheDataSource, url, manifest, bandwidthMeter,
    variantIndices, HlsChunkSource.ADAPTIVE_MODE_SPLICE, audioCapabilities);
```

Comment: where?! in which method or constructor?

Comment: Sorry for the slow response, you can do it in your HlsRendererBuilder.java

Comment: its not playing the video at all even at good bandwidth

Answer (score -2):

Yes, but you have to implement data cache on your own